# How to specify the path of a .class file to be dynamically loaded in its filesystem?

Tags: java, dynamic-loading

When a java program dynamically load a .class file,

- Is only the fully qualified classname of the .class file needed? Does `ClassLoader`
  s method `loadClass()` only require  the fully qualified classname of the .class file to be dynamically loaded?
- If the .class file can be located anywhere in a filesystem, how can I specify its  pathname in its filesystem?
- When running such the bytecode create from a Java program with command `java`, do I need to specify the path of the  .class file to be dynamically loaded in `-cp`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are conflating classes and ".class" files.

> Is only the fully qualified classname of the .class file needed? Does ClassLoader s method loadClass() only require the fully qualified classname of the .class file to be dynamically loaded?

The fully qualified class name **of the class** is required.

> If the .class file can be located anywhere in a filesystem ...

It cannot be!  The .class file corresponding to the class needs to be on the relevant classloader's classpath.

If you want to load a class from an arbitrary file in the file system, you need to create a new classloader instance:

- If you use one of the standard classloader implementations, it will use the standard scheme for resolving a .class file location based on the classes package names.
- It would be possible to implement a custom classloader that resolves FQ classnames to file system objects ... some other way.  But that seems unnecessary, since a standard Java compiler will emit `.class` files as per the standard scheme.

> When running such the bytecode create from a Java program with command java, do I need to specify the path of the .class file to be dynamically loaded in -cp?

You don't give the location of the .class file.  You give the location of a directory where the .class file can be resolved, as above.

But if a running Java program generates, compiles and then loads a class, it will need to *dynamically* create a new classloader to load it ... reliably.

Why?  Because classloaders typically cache the contents of directories and JAR indexes on the classpath.  So when a program writes a new file, the classloader may not get to know about it.

There is also the issue that a classloader cannot load the same class (from any location) twice.

Finally, be aware that if two classloaders load a class with the same fully qualified name, the runtime type system treats them as distinct classes / types.  You can't cast between the two incarnations of the type.